# collapsable content not indenting

Tags: html

I am loading some table content with collapse-panel, its in tabular format - like there are three rows and three columns , if i click on first column of first row which is header of that row , it expands and show its details, which again in tabular format, 
image attached - [before expanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl3qU.jpg)

[second image is when i click on orders , it expands and show its details.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/th94f.jpg)

the problem is .. when it expands , it shows its detailed table data only in its own column , as in image you can see "fsdfdsfds" column is excluded, i am trying to do that when it expands and show the details , it should show in a full row just below the entire row of main header ..

please see the code , any help ??

```
<table class="table">


<tr>
  <td>
     <a class="btn btn-default hide_retail" data-toggle="collapse" href="#show_retail" id="hide_retail">Orders</a>
     <div id="show_retail" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
           dsfsdfd
           <table class="table">
              <tr>
                 <td>sdfdsf</td>
                 <td>sfsdf</td>
                 <td>dsfsdf</td>
                 <td>sdfdsf</td>
                 <td>sdfdsf</td>
                 <td>sfsdf</td>
                 <td>dsfsdf</td>
                 <td>sfsdf</td>
                 <td>dsfsdf</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>sdfdsf</td>
                 <td>sfsdf</td>
                 <td>dsfsdf</td>
                 <td>sdfdsf</td>
                 <td>sdfdsf</td>
                 <td>sfsdf</td>
                 <td>dsfsdf</td>
                 <td>sfsdf</td>
                 <td>dsfsdf</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                 <td>sdfdsf</td>
                 <td>sfsdf</td>
                 <td>dsfsdf</td>
                 <td>sdfdsf</td>
                 <td>sdfdsf</td>
                 <td>sfsdf</td>
                 <td>dsfsdf</td>
                 <td>sfsdf</td>
                 <td>dsfsdf</td>
              </tr>
           </table>
        </div>
     </div>
  </td>


    <td>fsdfdsfds</td>
```

```
<tr>
  <td>fdsdf</td>
  <td>fddsfd</td>
```

UPDATE : SOLVED -- i got the solution -- here-- > https://www.bootply.com/glebkema/Qyh5hbEMdU

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem. Is this you want to do ? https://jsbin.com/zelevelaya

Comment: @Casper yes and its working like this only in my question's code, like i added : <td>#9847984</td> at the end of first td in your code, like orders show some figure , and when expanded it shows more - but when it expands the second td which i added in your code expands too , is there any way that when expanded it shows the result in a new row with all columns merged ??

Comment: Difficult to understand your problem, can you share workable code in fiddle or jsbin ?

Comment: Problem is with your HTML structure please try this without bootstrap https://jsbin.com/qevuwenima/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: yes, tried but not working . in your previous jsbin , ex:  <tr>
              <td>1</td>
              <td>2</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        <div>  
          </td> <td>#9847984</td> (i added this in your js) 
    </tr>
now when i click on orders it gives me structure like 
| orders | #9847984 |   (this second td goes in the middle)
|12        |                  |
so is there any way that i can keep the 1st and 2nd TD as it is .. but the expanded result 12 should display on the whole page merging the two TD of second row ?

Comment: Please update your changes and share the url.

Comment: @Casper https://jsbin.com/yijuceriva/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Casper something like this > but this is more complex for me -- 
https://stackblitz.com/angular/ygdrrokyvkv?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.html

Comment: okay i got the solution -- here-- > https://www.bootply.com/glebkema/Qyh5hbEMdU

Comment: I've added my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change structure of your `HTML`, here is the table what you asked,

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Column</th>
         <th>Column</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#r1">
       <td>Data</td>
       <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="r1" class="collapse out">
         <td>
            Table inside the td
             <table class="table">
                 <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
             </table>
          </td>
         <td>- Child column 2</td>
    </tr>
     <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#r2">
       <td>Data</td>
       <td>Data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="r2" class="collapse out">
         <td> - Child column 1</td>
         <td>- Child column 2</td>
    </tr>
 </table>
```